# Print output/s on nested if/else statements

Tags: java, if-statement, printf, java.util.scanner

Editing as the problem gets narrowed down:

```
ans1 = homeMortgage + annualTuition + annualCharity + healthCredit;
    if( grossAnnualIncome <= ans1 )
    {
    System.out.println( "YOU OWE $0.00 IN TAXES!" );
    }
    else if(grossAnnualIncome == 0)
    {
    System.out.println( "You earned no income so you owe no taxes!" );
    }
    else
    {
    //GROSS ANNUAL INCOME > 0 OUTPUT
    System.out.printf( "\nYOUR TAXES\n\n"
                    + "Gross Annual Income: %,.0f\n\n"
                    + "Deductions: \n"
                    + "\tHigher Education: %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tCharitable Contributions: %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tHome Mortgage Interest: %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tHealth Insurance Tax Credit: %,.0f\n\n"
                    + "Tax at 17%%: %,.0f\n"
                    + "Annual Income After Taxes: %,.0f\n"
                    + "Monthly Income After Taxes: %,.0f", grossAnnualIncome, annualTuition, annualCharity,
                       homeMortgage, healthCredit, taxAt17, annualAfterTaxes, monthlyAfterTaxes);
    }
```

grossAnnualIncome <= ans1 outputs correctly.

grossAnnualIncome == 0 outputs YOU OWE $0.00 IN TAXES! instead of You earned no income so you owe no taxes!

grossAnnualIncome > 0 outputs correctly.

Comment: Maybe you can use "else if" ?

Comment: If I enter 0 as gross anuual income, the program only prints: `You earned no income so you owe no taxes!` which seems to be what you expect - Not sure I understand what you want...

Comment: There needs to be an output for users who had income, but their tax credits exceeded their tax liability, thus the output reading YOU OWE $0.00 IN TAXES! I can get that to show, but it posts everything with grossAnnualIncome > 0 along with it, which I don't want.

Comment: I've read this a couple of times but I don't quite understand what your *whole* code would look like, or what behaviour you're expecting and not getting.  Could you perhaps create a much, much shorter example that illustrates your problem (e.g. just a single input for a single variable, and then three outputs based on that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT based on new question...

It's actually very simple what's happening here.  You're observing that the statement in the first block is printed.  This means that the first test condition was true - that is, `grossAnnualIncome` (zero) was less than `ans1` (also zero in this case).

I suspect the way to fix this would be to switch the order of the first two tests, so that the check for zero income takes priority.

In general, if you have conditions that might overlap, make sure you order the tests in an `if - else if - else ...` block so that the most specific one appears first.

---

(And by the way, if you're just outputting a simple string it's more usual to call `System.out.print` (or `println`) rather than printf.  No point making Java format nothing after all, and I found it slightly disorienting.)

Comment: OK, this fixed my 3rd output statement, but I'm having issues with the 2nd one below. Let me re-edit my post above.

Comment: That was it. Duly noted on the if - else if - else overlap and starting with the most specific condition first. It makes sense to do that now that I think about it, but did not know it would cause problems if you were not to.

Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you could just move the last output out of the `if( grossAnnualIncome > 0 )`-statement, and print it later:

```
if( grossAnnualIncome > 0 )
    {

    //... You do a whole lot of stuff here that i removed in my example
    // to make it easier to read.

    taxableIncome = grossAnnualIncome - homeMortgage - annualTuition - annualCharity - healthCredit;
        taxAt17 = taxableIncome * .17;
        annualAfterTaxes = grossAnnualIncome - taxAt17;
        monthlyAfterTaxes = annualAfterTaxes / 12;
        ans1 = homeMortgage + annualTuition + annualCharity + healthCredit;


     // Here I removed the output and moved it to the else statement below, to only
     // print it if income is greater than 0

}

  if( grossAnnualIncome <= 0 )
  {
      System.out.printf( "You earned no income so you owe no taxes!" );
  } else {
      System.out.printf( "\nYOUR TAXES\n\n"
                    + "Gross Annual Income: %,.0f\n\n"
                    + "Deductions: \n"
                    + "\tHigher Education: %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tCharitable Contributions: %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tHome Mortgage Interest: %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tHealth Insurance Tax Credit: %,.0f\n\n"
                    + "Tax at 17%%: %,.0f\n"
                    + "Annual Income After Taxes: %,.0f\n"
                    + "Monthly Income After Taxes: %,.0f", grossAnnualIncome, annualTuition, annualCharity,
                       homeMortgage, healthCredit, taxAt17, annualAfterTaxes, monthlyAfterTaxes);
}
```